# Email Results from Long PHP Script

Tags: php, email

I need to process a long PHP script and have the results emailed to the user once the script has completed. How is this done?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: It would be good to include and example of the code you are working with.  That way it might be more clear what kind of a suggestion should be made.

Comment: I need to understand the basic architecture of taking the request, putting it in a que and processing the script independently from my web application. I can not find much on the internet.

Comment: The script I have runs fine and I'm sure I can generate the email. How does one decouple the PHP script from the web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the `mail()` function. You need an SMTP server set up on your server to do so. See details in the documentation: http://php.net/mail

Edit: if you use PHPmailer class, you can simply save the pdf and

```
$mail->AddAttachment("document.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm cool with mail(). But I need to run this in the background (not in a new tab) then email. Here is my script:'<?php
ob_start();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{
}
$pdf = new PDF('P','in','Letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,45);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Ln(5.35);
$pdf->Cell(0.3);
$pdf->Cell(0,0, "Run this script and email it. Don't open it in a new tab. Just run it on the server and email the output PDF");
$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();
?>'I just need to run this on the server and email the output.

Comment: The mail headers allow you to attach files. The pdf you generate should be stored as `application/pdf` and not some random MIME (`application/octet-stream` and so on) for correct attachment format. For more, please read the `mail()` documentation. I'm not willing to write your code, just guide you through the way.

Comment: I don't need to have code written for me. The mail() function is not the issue. How do you run any PHP script on the server without tying up the client?

Comment: You can do it using scheduled cronjobs or a private admin surface.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that you really need to decouple the script from PHP, but if that's really what you are wanting to do, you can set a value in a MySQL table to reflect that the script has finished.  Then, run a cron job to check to see if the value in MySQL is set.  If so, send out the mail.  If not, go back to sleep and check again next minute.